# git apply --recount does not work for me

Tags: javascript, git, user-interface

I'm trying to emulate the 'stage line' functionality provided by native git-gui app.
My project: https://github.com/demian85/git-watcher

I saw there is an option `--recount` that is supposed to recount the edited lines in the patch so I don't have to work on a really complicated logic using complex regular expressions.

So, what I'm trying to do is `git diff`, edit the patch by removing unwanted lines (leaving the context lines untouched) and then `git apply --cached --recount patch.diff`.

Unfortunately I'm getting the error:

```
error: patch failed: core.js:24
error: core.js: patch does not apply
```

Is there a way to make git actually recount lines in the patch?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I just found the problem. To leave just one line to delete or add, I need to leave the other lines as "neutral" by removing the "-" or "+" sign at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Nice work. Can you mark you own answer as accepted so people with the same issue in the future know it's the solution?